# CSS - How to properly implement a form input-based image

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to properly use CSS in order to display an image based on valid form feedback?

Essentially I want to display a custom green check mark image or red X image on each form input line based on valid/invalid data, respectively. Is there a way to have this image appear inside the input box, right-aligned?

Thank you!

Update: Adding the image was as simple as including it within the "input:invalid" area of my css page. Now I just need to know how to have it only appear once and preferably right-aligned.

Comment: I think you could use `div` tag as the wrapper, and `position:absolute`.

Comment: are you using and frame work such as bootstrap?

Comment: It's a school assignment and we are supposed to do it without div. No boostrap or anything fancy, very simple html form with some css

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this I think [this][1] is what you need:

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="" class="input">

.input{
background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/20X20/ffffff/0a0a0a&text=x');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I came up with lol. You posted this as I was preparing my comment.

Comment: yah thats simple :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with based on background image coding but within an input CSS container (if that makes sense... still new to this):

```
input:valid {
    background-color: #5CEC87;
    background-image: url(green_checkmark.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}


input:invalid {
    background-color: #FD9191;
    background-image: url(red_asterisk.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
```

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Nothing! Just wanted to share my solution just in case anyone else stumbled upon this post with the same question and/or for personal future reference.